# How To change bottom bar color in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am creating an app which shows the result of our university students but in my app, the bottom bar of app color does not change how can I change the color of the bottom bar in flutter here I post an image
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pfus.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Here is an article on many different ways to change the navigation bar color
https://blog.devgenius.io/different-ways-to-change-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-color-ios-and-android-in-flutter-a786e098f573

Comment: I think it changes in the android and iOS part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want to change the color of your system navigation bar

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.red,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

this will change its color.

Comment: How can i change on every screen I use this and work perfectley but On other screen i need to use diffrent color but that didn't worked plz help